# Is a 1660 Ti compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card

I own a Dell Precision Tower 5810 and i’d like to know if a GTX 1660 Ti is compatible with its motherboard (K240Y Precision)
I’d apologize in advance for the ignorance but i’ve searched for a while yet haven’t found a concrete answer

Comment: This might be better answered at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: It should be fine. The graphics card uses the same interface and version of the motherboard, PCIe 3.0 x16.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Why is that? It's not a recommendation question. It's a "is this compatible or not" question.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all graphics cards branded GTX 1660 Ti you can buy are standard-ish PCI Express device, so you can insert it into any PCI Express x16 slot.

Here is an example of a PCI Express x16 slot:

[image: A PCIe x16 slot]